# Newton's method linear convergence proof

Tags: numerical-methods

How would you show that if f'(a)=0 then the Newton's Method is linear convergent when
1. $f''(a)\neq 0$
2. $f''(a)=0, f'''(a) \neq 0$?
I am having some trouble getting it to the point where you can take the limit of ratio of the error terms and using L'hospital's rule to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x)=(x-a)^2g(x)$ resp. $f(x)=(x-a)^3g(x)$, both with $g(a)\ne0$ and compute the influence of these factorizations on the Newton iteration.

---

If $f(x)=(x-a)^mg(x)$ with $g(a)\ne 0$ then $f'(x)=m(x-a)^{m-1}g(x)+(x-a)^mg'(x)$ and
$$
x_+=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=x-\frac{(x-a)g(x)}{mg(x)+(x-a)g'(x)}=a+(x-a)\frac{(m-1)g(x)+(x-a)g'(x)}{mg(x)+(x-a)g'(x)}
$$
For $x$ close to $a$ the term $(x-a)g'(x)$ becomes very small relative to $g(x)$, and the Newton iteration reduces to 
$$
x_+=a+(1-\tfrac1m)(x-a).
$$
For a strict proof you have to quantify "becomes very small relative to" and use inequalities for $|x_+-a|\leqslant C|x-a|$, but the general idea is as above.

Comment: can you please explain more?  I thought I did that but its not turning out any answer.

Comment: Hi @LutzL a bit late here but hoping you see this. How do you know you are able to write $f$ in the form $f(x)=(x-a)^mg(x)$ when we have $f^{(n)}\neq 0$? Something to do with Taylor expanding $f$ or $g$?

Comment: Yes, or by the definition of multiplicity, $f$ has a root of multiplicity $m$ at $a$ if it can be factorized as $f(x)=(x-a)^mg(x)$ with $g(a)\ne0 $.

Comment: @LutzL is this assuming that $f$ is a polynomial then (since we're talking about multiplicity)?

Comment: No, this is a general definition for $f$ sufficiently smooth in $a$. You can very well say that all roots of $1+\sin x$ have multiplicity $2$.